# Dynamics CRM Plugin Registration Tool can't Log In - No error message

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

My CRM Version

```
Microsoft Dynamics 365 Version 1612 (9.0.0.3172) (DB 9.0.0.3172) online
```

The more recent SDK download from Microsofts website (version 8.2.1.1).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=50032

**Problem**

I get no error message it just returns back to the login screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the CRM is on version `9.0.0.3172` and the SDK is on `8.2.1.1`

Microsoft has prevented you from getting the most recent version of the SDK by monolithic download only the old version is accessible via their website.

if you want to read more into the problem you can view Syed Ibrahim's blog [here](http://mscrm365.blogspot.sg/2018/01/dynamics-crm-v9-connection-error-in.html)

The new version of Dynamics to 9.0 version will require the last version 9.0.0.7 of PluginRegistrationTool

You can get it by downloading it through NuGet in Visual Studio instance. Just typing PluginRegistrationTool and search for the 9.0.0.7 version.  Or through power shell.

Here you have the instructions:

**Method #1: Using Visual Studio (Package Manager Console):**

1. Create a new Console application in Visual Studio
2. Open Tools --> Nuget Package Manager Console
3. Copy and paste the command below from this article into the Package Manager Console:
   Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PackageDeployment -Version 9.0.0.7
4. Check the location where the package was installed:

· You will be able to find Plugin Registration tool in the Package location of the solution folder.

**Method #2: Using Windows Powershell:**

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/download-tools-nuget

In your Windows Start menu, type Windows Powershell and open it.

Navigate to the folder you want to install the tools to. For example if you want to install them in a devtools folder on your D drive, type cd D:\devtools.
Copy and paste the following PowerShell script into the PowerShell window and press Enter

```
$sourceNugetExe = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
$targetNugetExe = ".\nuget.exe"
Remove-Item .\Tools -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
Invoke-WebRequest $sourceNugetExe -OutFile $targetNugetExe
Set-Alias nuget $targetNugetExe -Scope Global -Verbose

##
##Download Plugin Registration Tool
##
./nuget install Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PluginRegistrationTool -O .\Tools
md .\Tools\PluginRegistration
$prtFolder = Get-ChildItem ./Tools | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PluginRegistrationTool.'}
move .\Tools\$prtFolder\tools\*.* .\Tools\PluginRegistration
Remove-Item .\Tools\$prtFolder -Force -Recurse

##
##Download CoreTools
##
./nuget install  Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools -O .\Tools
md .\Tools\CoreTools
$coreToolsFolder = Get-ChildItem ./Tools | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools.'}
move .\Tools\$coreToolsFolder\content\bin\coretools\*.* .\Tools\CoreTools
Remove-Item .\Tools\$coreToolsFolder -Force -Recurse

##
##Download Configuration Migration
##
./nuget install  Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.ConfigurationMigration.Wpf -O .\Tools
md .\Tools\ConfigurationMigration
$configMigFolder = Get-ChildItem ./Tools | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.ConfigurationMigration.Wpf.'}
move .\Tools\$configMigFolder\tools\*.* .\Tools\ConfigurationMigration
Remove-Item .\Tools\$configMigFolder -Force -Recurse

##
##Download Package Deployer 
##
./nuget install  Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PackageDeployment.WPF -O .\Tools
md .\Tools\PackageDeployment
$pdFolder = Get-ChildItem ./Tools | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.PackageDeployment.Wpf.'}
move .\Tools\$pdFolder\tools\*.* .\Tools\PackageDeployment
Remove-Item .\Tools\$pdFolder -Force -Recurse

##
##Remove NuGet.exe
##
Remove-Item nuget.exe
```

Navigate to the download location and you should be able to find the tool.